# Problem with GraphQL finding method on queryResolver

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, graphql

I'm working on a GraphQL java API project and i'm having problems with the Query not finding the methods in the Query.java (QueryResolver)

I can't see an error on this code but aparently it has one ':D

PS: I use java open JDK 11

the error: (full stacktrace on https://pastebin.com/cpVRpdsj)

```java
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean]: Factory method 'graphQLServlet' threw exception; nested exception is com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.FieldResolverError: No method or field found with any of the following signatures (with or without one of [interface graphql.schema.DataFetchingEnvironment] as the last argument), in priority order:

  com.example.GraphQLRProject.core.Query.findAllPessoas()
  com.example.GraphQLRProject.core.Query.getFindAllPessoas()
  com.example.GraphQLRProject.core.Query.findAllPessoas
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:650) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    ... 59 common frames omitted
```

my pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>GraphQLRProject</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>GraphQLRProject</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <!--<kotlin.version>1.3.10</kotlin.version> -->
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>   
    
        <!-- 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>    
        -->

    
        <!-- 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.graphql-java-kickstart</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphql-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
         -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphql-java-tools</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphql-java</artifactId>
            <version>11.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphql-java-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphiql-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.6</version>
        </dependency>   
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>           
        <!-- GraphQL end -->    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

my Query.java

```java
package com.example.GraphQLRProject.core;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.GraphQLQueryResolver;
import com.example.GraphQLRProject.model.Pessoa;
import com.example.GraphQLRProject.repository.PessoaRepository;

@Component
public class Query implements GraphQLQueryResolver {

    @Autowired
    PessoaRepository pessoaRepository;

    List<Pessoa> findAllPessoas() {
        return pessoaRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

my main application

```java
package com.example.GraphQLRProject;

import java.util.TimeZone;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

import com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.SchemaParser;
import com.example.GraphQLRProject.core.Mutation;
import com.example.GraphQLRProject.core.Query;
import com.example.GraphQLRProject.util.DateScalar;

import graphql.schema.GraphQLSchema;
import graphql.servlet.SimpleGraphQLHttpServlet;

@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = GraphQlrProjectApplication.class)
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.example")
@EntityScan("com.example")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.example")
@SuppressWarnings({"rawtypes", "unchecked"})
public class GraphQlrProjectApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GraphQlrProjectApplication.class, args);
    }

    @PostConstruct
    void started() {
        TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Recife"));
    }
    
    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean graphQLServlet() {
        return new ServletRegistrationBean(SimpleGraphQLHttpServlet.newBuilder(buildSchema()).build(), "/graphql");
    }

    private static GraphQLSchema buildSchema() {
        return SchemaParser
                .newParser()
                .file("schema.graphqls")
                .resolvers(new Query(), new Mutation())
                .scalars(DateScalar.DATE)
                .build()
                .makeExecutableSchema();
    }
}
```

and my schema.graphqls

```
schema {
    query: Query
    mutation: Mutation
}

type Query {
    findAllPessoas: [Pessoa]
}

type Mutation {
    savePessoa(novo: PessoaInput): Pessoa
}

type Pessoa {
    id: ID!
    nome: String!
    cpf: String!
    email: String!
}

input PessoaInput{
    nome: String!
    cpf: String!
    email: String!
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that the method was not public ...

big facepalm for me ':D