graphQL - Problem with define pagination in schema
My goal is to define a paginated schema using connections (cursor, edges, etc.), but I have a problem with nested collections...
I'm using spring-boot v2.7.12 (without graphql starter - this version doesnt support directives *Connections) and graphql-java-kickstart (tools and also spring-boot-starter)
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.graphql-java-kickstart</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphql-java-tools</artifactId>
            <version>13.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.graphql-java-kickstart</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphql-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>14.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

schema.graphqls
type Container{
    name:String
}

type Guide{
    name: String
    containers(first: Int, after: String): ContainerConnection  @connection(for: "Container")
}


type Query {
    guides:[Guide]
}

GuideController
@Controller
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class GuideController implements GraphQLQueryResolver {
    private final GuideRepository guideRepository;

    List<Guide> guides() {
        return ....
    }
}

ContainerController
@Controller
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ContainerController implements GraphQLQueryResolver {
    private final ContainerRepository containerRepository;

    public Connection<Container> containers(Integer first, String after, DataFetchingEnvironment env) {
        return ....
    }
}

When the application is starting I got error
Caused by: graphql.kickstart.tools.resolver.FieldResolverError: No method found as defined in schema <unknown>:7 with any of the following signatures (with or without one of [interface graphql.schema.DataFetchingEnvironment, class graphql.GraphQLContext] as the last argument), in priority order:

  guide.entity.Guide.containers(~first, ~after)
  guide.entity.Guide.getContainers(~first, ~after)
    at graphql.kickstart.tools.resolver.FieldResolverScanner.missingFieldResolver(FieldResolverScanner.kt:82) ~[graphql-java-tools-13.0.0.jar:?]
    at graphql.kickstart.tools.resolver.FieldResolverScanner.findFieldResolver(FieldResolverScanner.kt:42) ~[graphql-java-tools-13.0.0.jar:?]
    at graphql.kickstart.tools.SchemaClassScanner.scanResolverInfoForPotentialMatches(SchemaClassScanner.kt:273) ~[graphql-java-tools-13.0.0.jar:?]

Why the resolver mapping containers method from Guide entity not from Controller? How to do that?
When I tried simple mapping for Guide or Container pagination, everything is fine
type Guide{
    name: String
}


type Query {
    guides[(first: Int, after: String) : GuideConnection  @connection(for: "Guide")]
    guide(id: Int) : Guide
}

    public Connection<Guide> guides(Integer first, String after, DataFetchingEnvironment env) {
        return new SimpleListConnection<>(List.of()).get(env);
    }

For example: This is works but not solve my problem.2

The Java Object fields should have the exact same name as the Schema field names, otherwise it will throw the FieldResolverError. Also check the method visibility like mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62735284/problem-with-graphql-finding-method-on-queryresolver
